# Can not read IndexedDB sqlite file with JavaScript in readable format

Tags: javascript, sqlite, encoding, blob

This is some contents I have obtained from the IndexedDB storage sqlite file of a locally hosted website. (obtained from Mozilla Firefox)

```
SQLite format 3@  �.O| �;��  [�������- 3�triggerfile_update_triggerfileCREATE TRIGGER file_update_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON file FOR EACH ROW WHEN NEW..
..
��tabledatabasedatabaseCREATE TABLE database( name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, origin TEXT NOT NULL, version INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_vacuum_time INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_analyze_time INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, last_vacuum_size INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0) WITHOUT ROWID ��'- reduxhttp://localhostƸ&~ʘ�
```

I have obtained it with JavaScript function
reader.readAsText(file);

Since it is for forensic analysis, I can not obtain it with regular IndexedDB functions. Same Origin Policy does not allow me. This one is from localhost but there are some other websites with the same problem.

If I read it as reader.readAsArrayBuffer it gives me this:
[object ArrayBuffer] as output

Right click + inspect + storage + Indexed DB shows it nicely but I can not always use it again with Same Origin Policy.

I tried every encoding but I can not translate it to right display. Some characters are represented as ? and in some other encodings as boxes. For example http://localhost has some characters misrepresented at the end.
Any way I can obtain it in a readable form ?

EDIT

The data is displayed without any problems in developer tools of Firefox and Chrome. I can also reach to my own site's data through this developer tools. I can also access to it with the IndexedDB code as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API

These data is stored in a .sqlite file under C:\Users<userprofile>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles<profile>\storage\default\

My problem is that I need to parse this data when this data is obtained externally from someone's computer with logical extraction. I tried making my own website and swapping the .sqlite files to display data. It didnt work

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFGT.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to :- [SQLite Database File Format](https://sqlite.org/fileformat.html).

The initial data is from the header (first 100 bytes) as SQLite format 3. is > `0   16  The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"`

You need to read it using SQLite (e.g. SQLite tools such as Navicat for SQLite, DBeaver, DB Browser .... ) or do a lot of work to write your own reader.

However, from what you have displayed, the header doesn't appear to be long enough. It looks as though the header is only 46 bytes instead of 100. You wouldn;t get `triggerfile_update` in the header.

Perhaps view it in a hex capable editor e.g. NotePad++ has a Hex Editor plugin. using this then the header of a sample SQLite database looks like:-

[image]

It's not until much later that the data for the schema (definitions of tables etc) appear:-

[image]

So it may be that somehow the file is corrupted.

Comment: I tried DB Browser and some other tools, all have those characters missing. DB Browser displays it as binary but unreadable characters are converted to '...' still not readable. For example 'username' string displayed as 'use..?rname' while it appears right in the developer tools.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I really appreciate it. I made an edit to the question.